# Method App\Http\Controllers\LanguagesController::index does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

LARAVEL
[image: error!!]

when I make a **controller** insid folder called "Admin" by command
"php artisan make:controller Admin\ControllerLanguages"

and Route the page This error appears:

> Method App\Http\Controllers\LanguagesController::index does not exist.
> Bad Method Call Did you mean
> App\Http\Controllers\LanguagesController::validate() ?

but when i make the **controller** normally in the default folder by command:
"php artisan make:controller LanguagesController"

the route runs and the page appears, i want the page appears when i create it in "Admin" Folder, I tried many ways, but to no avail.

[image: Controller Code]
[image: Route Code]

Comment: Hey. It looks like you miswrote this in your first part: ControllerLanguages. It should be LanguagesController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the namespace for the route group

```php
Route::prefix('languages')
    ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Admin')
    ->group(function() {
        Route::get('/', 'LanguagesController@index')->name('admin.languages');
        //All other Routes for languages defined here
        //LanguagesController is at app/Http/Controllers/Admin folder
    });
```

Or you can import the namespace via `use` statement like, at the top

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LanguagesController;

Route::prefix('languages')
    ->group(function(){
        Route::get('/', [LanguagesController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.languages');

        //Other languages routes here
    });
```

Comment: i tried twice But the result in both cases:

Comment: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LanguagesController] does not exist.

Comment: Getting error with which option - first or second?

Comment: first

Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LanguagesController] does not exist.

second 

yes the page ran thanks a lot